# How do I bring List Items to the front of menu items?

Tags: html, css

Title is confusing I know. So I'll just explain with pictures.

This is the full window view of the navigation bar:

[image]

This is when I lower the screen resolution:

[image]

the items list goes behind menu items. How do I bring them to the front?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check your HTML structure, target your "sub-level" container(the list which will drop-down), and be sure to have a `position` value for it, so the `z-index` value would work. Then add a `z-index` value(and check if you have any other z-index values which may interfere with your navigation menu).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It wasn't working without specifying position.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the z-index of the items.

zindex of items > menu

Comment: what value? I added it and it didnt work

Comment: add a big value 9999999. It should be bigger than z-index of menu(check if menu has any z-index set)

Answer (score 0):

here is the css you're looking for

```
.menu > li{
    z-index:100;
}
```

*Z-index* allows you to "stack" items within the depth of the screen. Items with lower values (-25) are stacked below or more appropriately behind items of greater value (0 or 100).